# Nuget Update-Package -reinstall is failing with InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with 3 projects. Each of them has a `packages.config` file that looks like below:

Project 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Project 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net40-Client" requireReinstallation="True" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
</packages>
```

Project 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

I would like to do a clean install of these dependencies. I'm using Nuget Package Manager Version 2.8.60318.667 and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition.

I ran the following command in Nuget Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

And I get the following message:

```
PM> Update-Package -reinstall
Reinstalling 'log4net 2.0.8' in project 'Project 2'.
Removing 'log4net 2.0.8' from Project 2.
Successfully removed 'log4net 2.0.8' from Project 2.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' in project 'Project 2'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from Project 2.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from Project 2.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' in project 'Project 2'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' from Project 2.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' from Project 2.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' in project 'Project 2'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from Project 2.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from Project 2.
Reinstalling 'log4net 2.0.8' in project 'Project 1'.
Removing 'log4net 2.0.8' from Project 1.
Successfully removed 'log4net 2.0.8' from Project 1.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' in project 'Project 1'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from Project 1.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from Project 1.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' in project 'Project 1'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' from Project 1.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' from Project 1.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21'.
Access to the path 'C:\path-to-project\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.
Access to the path 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21'.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' in project 'Project 1'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from Project 1.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from Project 1.
Reinstalling 'log4net 2.0.8' in project 'Project 3'.
Removing 'log4net 2.0.8' from Project 3.
Successfully removed 'log4net 2.0.8' from Project 3.
Uninstalling 'log4net 2.0.8'.
Successfully uninstalled 'log4net 2.0.8'.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' in project 'Project 3'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from Project 3.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' from Project 3.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10'.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' in project 'Project 3'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' from Project 3.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' from Project 3.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'.
Access to the path 'C:\Users\path-to-project\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.
Access to the path 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'.
Reinstalling 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' in project 'Project 3'.
Removing 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from Project 3.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' from Project 3.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.AppContext (≥ 4.1.0)'.
Update-Package : 'System.AppContext' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Runtime'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand
```

I tried running VS 2010 as Administrator but no luck. Can anyone help? Thanks.